# Как изменить положение ползунка QSlider через connect?

Tags: c++, qt5

Проблема состоит вот в чем. Нужно, чтобы при изменении объекта изменялось положение ползунка QSlider'а.

Пытался вот так изменять:

```
connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged()), ui->horizontalSlider, QSlider::setValue(player->position()));
```

Но Slider не имеет такого слота. Хотя если отдельно писать

```
ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(player->position());
```

то все работает. Как тогда его изменять?

Comment: В слайдере, то есть в его предке QAbstractSlider есть слот setValue принимающий значение целого типа, чтобы его связать в коннекте вам надо  в сигнале positionChanged добавить аргумент позиции целого типа. То есть в коде делать emit positionChanged(position);

Comment: Во-первых, если писать так: QSlider::setValue(... , то выходит ошибка, что Slider не имеет такой слот. Хорошо я изменил ее. Добавил значение и написал SLOT. connect(player, SIGNAL(positionChanged(1000)), ui->horizontalSlider, SLOT(setValue(player->position()))); Ошибок нет. Но теперь пишет такого сигнала нет. No such signal QMediaPlayer::positionChanged(1000)

Comment: А, так это у вас QMediaPlayer? А я только начинающий медиум, извините. Ваш коннекте выглядит так connect(player,  &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::setValue);

Comment: Ого. Спасибо, все работает. Но можно поинтересоваться, как он автоматически устанавливает значение, ведь мы в setValue ничего не кладем. И что значит вот этот знак -> &. Ссылка?

Comment: В документации у QMediaPlayer указан сигнал positionChanged(qint64 pos) вот этот pos и передаётся в QSlider::setValue. Амперсанд & формирует указатели на функции-слоты класса